# Why ssh port forwarding doesn't work on external IP interface while work on 127.0.0.1

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

```
Machines:
Host laptop: 192.168.0.5
VirtualBox VM with NAT Network Adapter: 192.168.56.101
```

If I run this it doesn't work if I open in the browser `192.168.0.5:30012`:

```
ssh -L 30012:192.168.0.5:8080 -N -f -l usersu 192.168.56.101
```

But this works perfectly fine:

```
ssh -L 30012:127.0.0.1:8080 -N -f -l usersu 192.168.56.101
```

I also added the rule in UFW to allow 30012. What am I doing wrong?

I need to do this port forwarding from VirtualBox VM in which I do web site development. I wanted to check the web site using mobile device.

The VirtualBox VM has two network interfaces NAT and host only. For some reason Virtual Box NAT port forwarding stopped to work (Host and guest restart did not help). I decided to use SSH port forwarding. But it only works on `127.0.0.1`.

I know I could add 3rd network inteface "Bridged Adapter" in VirtualBox to get a new IP in local network but this solution I don't like because it introduces some complexity.

`192.168.56.101` is the host only network interface of VirtualBox VM. I can access it only from host and guest VMs, but not from mobile phone which is connected to the local network which is `192.168.0.x`.

Tried to use this

```
ssh -L 30012:0.0.0.0:8080 -N -f -l usersu 192.168.56.101
```

It works for 127.0.0.1, but doesn't work for 192.168.0.5.

Based on the [@Giacomo1968’s comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1429338/why-ssh-port-forwarding-doesnt-work-on-external-ip-interface-while-work-on-127#comment2157301_1429338) at the moment I use workaround in which I added 3rd Bridged Network interface and for webpack did this change [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49323685/1325696).

Comment: You normally cannot communicate with your local intranet address on the localhost.  Why exactly are you against using localhost (127.0.0.1)?  The formatting of your question makes your question hard to read.  You should edit your question to clearly indicate which command is working.

Comment: Most likely your application is set to only bind to localhost (`127.0.0.1`) when if you want the application to network off of your device you need to bind to `0.0.0.0` or even `192.168.56.101`. The `0.0.0.0` would bind your application to any port on your machine where `192.168.56.101` would only bind to that specific IP address.

Comment: @JakeGould - Any port or any address?  Wouldn’t 0.0.0.0 be my address on a given port? (Whatever port SSH is set to)

Comment: @Ramhound Binding a server to `0.0.0.0` tells most applications: “Use any network interface on this machine and bind the application to that interface.”  But when the user says they want to connect their app to the LAN, this idea might not work since LAN access would imply the host would need to be accessible on the LAN. This advice I posted would work for the guest. The real solution is to use “Bridged Mode” and allow the VM to be a part of the LAN despite the claims of “complexity” raised by the original poster. Bridged mode is the only real solution here.

Comment: @user1325696 Did my comments solve your issue?

Comment: @JakeGould not yet because of the complexities. The problem left is  to change webpack to work on the newly network interface as by default it works on localhost. I modified and the change seems doesn't work.

Comment: It's not clear to me which address belongs to where; where you run this `ssh` command; what is local, what is remote; from where you try to enter the tunnel. But I know the address between `30012:` and `:8080` is *not the one `sshd` will bind to*. It's where packets will be sent to on the remote side. So `0.0.0.0` makes no sense. To specify bind address, you need it `here:30012:not_here:8080`. See `man 1 ssh`, `-L` option.

Comment: Erratum: in my comment above, where it says `sshd`, it should be `ssh`.